# NSURLConnectionでプロキシ経由での通信

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, network

表題の通りなのですが、NSURLConnectionを利用して、
プロキシ設定を行い特定のURLに接続する方法はないのでしょうか？
iOSシステム側の設定ではなく、NSURLConnectionの特定の通信の時だけ
プロキシ経由で接続するようにしたいです。

※既存ソース改修の都合上、NSURLSessionを利用することが厳しいです。

Comment: 質問をさらに具体的にしませんか？また、プロキシという言葉は意味が広すぎるため、プロキシという言葉を使わずに質問文を組み立てたほうが良いです。おそらくやりたいことは単純なことなのだとは思いますが、プロキシという言葉がノイズに感じます。